# Speed of standard Python data persistence methods

Tags: python, database, persistence

Do you know what speed difference are of:

- pickle
- shelve
- sqlite
- some MySQL connector
- MongoDB
- ...

If I wanted to store many dicts, which would be the prefered way and what are differences?

Comment: I would say this question will create too much discussion for SO - the only good answer here is 'it depends'.

Comment: Really? I mean I could write test suites where I store and retrieve 10000 dict, but that will take a while. Isn't it a clear task? But I know there are questions where people freak out for some reason :(

Comment: What do your dicts contain? Are you only accessing it from Python code, or do you need to access it from other places? What resources do you have available (separate DB server)? Are you always going to know the source of your data? Is security a concern? What existing code is there and what does that use? There are a myriad of details that would change the answer to this question.

Comment: No server, no existing code. I only want to write a program that locally stores string to string dicts in a file or whatever. No more fancy than that.

Comment: Why don't you write your own test code?

Comment: How many key/value pairs matters. Whether you want fast indexed lookup or will be deserializing the entire file on each read matters. The comments help to clarify a little, but the question itself contains far, _far_ too few details to be answerable.

Comment: So if you mention serialization just write it as an answer. Given the question only requires speed for dict storage it's possible to write test code which would yield a clear answer. I was hoping that some can short-cut this (installing/learning all of the methods). It's a pity when people are "too smart" to be able to give an answer. No where it mentions overly fancy stuff I don't need.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to drag out the comments, so I'll answer.

Given what you have said:

> No server, no existing code. I only want to write a program that locally stores string to string dicts in a file or whatever. No more fancy than that.

I would say your best bet for something so simple is probably something like [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

However, if you need to to be super-fast, it may not be the best solution (or it may be - I honestly don't know how it performs in comparison). It's simple, and there are implementations of it for most platforms, which covers a lot of the ground you want. If you want the best speed possible, my advice would be to test it, that's the only way you'll know for sure. Of course, simple is usually a good sign for speed.

You haven't given enough information to know how important performance is here. Remember, unless you **need** the performance (provably) then don't bother optimising until you do. Go for something easy to read and maintain code-side, and easy to work with file-side. This is why I recommend JSON.

Answer (score 1):

For persistent string to string dict's, anydbm is pretty reasonable.  bsddb can be used from anydbm, and is fast but a bit sensitive to being interrupted.  gdbm can be used from anydbm, and is slower but not likely to yield a corrupted database.

Also, if you want to read an entire dict into memory, make a lot of changes, and write the resulting dict back out, there's: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/dohdbm/trunk/  I'm using this one in a backup software project.  It'll compress your dictionaries if you want, which can be a performance win if your I/O is particularly slow, or you have a lot of modifications to make.